# Oracle INSERT giving error in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, insert

```
DbCommand command = new OracleCommand(
       "insert into hardware (HardwareID) VALUES (6);", myConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`Hardware` is a `NUMBER(7, 0)`.

I am trying to make this simple Oracle INSERT work using C#.  However, I keep getting an `911` error saying that there is an invalid character.

What am I doing wrong?

I can execute the following code without problems:

```
DbCommand command2 = new OracleCommand("Select * from Hardware", myConnection);
command2.ExecuteReader();
```

(I plan on using parameters later, I am just trying to get a proof-of-concept built)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can't add the ';' at the end. So try:

```
DbCommand command = new OracleCommand(
       "insert into hardware (HardwareID) VALUES (6)", myConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I believe Good Charlotte put it best: "Its the little things, the little things, that always bring you down. Thanks! `:D`

Comment: sheesh - that was my first thought, but I tossed that out thinking: nah, it can't be *that* obvious and simple :-(